# Can Doctrine QueryBuilder andWhere() used without where()?

Tags: doctrine, query-builder, doctrine-query

In Doctrine, when building a query with QueryBuilder, does the first `where`clause have to be defined with `$qb->where()`or can I use `$qb->andWhere()` directly. For example, is this valid:

```
$qb->select('Mystuff\Entity\User','u');
$qb->andWhere('usertype = :usertype');
$qb->andWhere('usercategory = :usercategory');
```

Or, as a more relevant example:

```
$filter = array('usertype'=>'basic','usercategory'=>'business');
$qb->select('Mystuff\Entity\User','u');
foreach ($filter as $fkey => $fval) {
   $qb->andWhere($fkey.' = :'.$fval);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes that will work. `where()` deletes any other criteria before adding those submitted, while `andWhere()` appends to an `AND` expression with any existing criteria.

Comment: Source : PHPDOC doctrine